# python aiohttp websockets closed browser tab handling

Tags: python, websocket, redis, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to create simple active users counter using `aiohttp` WebSockets and `aioredis` for storage. When I add a new tab in `Google Chrome`, my counter increments perfectly in all already opened tabs. However, when I close a tab, nothing changes in other tabs.

I think I should be missing something in whole async/await machinery, but cannot find what can be wrong.

Here is my app

```
import asyncio

import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web
import aioredis


class CounterView(web.View):
    async def get(self):
        request = self.request
        app = request.app

        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()

        app['websockets'].append(ws)
        await ws.prepare(request)

        count = int(await app['db'].incr('counter'))
        for ws in app['websockets']:
            await ws.send_json({'msg': {'count': count}})

        async for msg in ws:
            if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                await ws.send_str(msg.data)
            elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
                print('ws connection closed with exception %s' %
                      ws.exception())
        app['websockets'].remove(ws)

        # Execution stops here (on await app['db'] ...) and never returns
        count = int(await app['db'].decr('counter'))
        for ws in app['websockets']:
            await ws.send_json({'msg': {'count': count}})
        return ws


async def init_app(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    db = await aioredis.create_redis('redis://localhost', loop=loop)
    app['db'] = db
    app['websockets'] = []
    app.add_routes([
        web.get('', CounterView),
    ])
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    web.run_app(init_app(loop))
```

And index.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    How many people seeing this page now: <span id="counter"></span>
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
      const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
      ws.onmessage = function (event) {
          const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
          let span = document.getElementById('counter');
          console.log(data.msg.count);
          span.innerHTML = data.msg.count;
      }
    };
</script>
</html>
```

I have also tried in `Firefox`, and some really weird things happens there.

Opened two tabs, got `counter = 2` on both. Then reload first - got `1` in it and still `2` in second one. Reload first tab again - got `2`. After this, each reload gives `2`.

Until I reload second tab - the same process (reload - `1` - reload - `2` happens there and repeats in first tab)

Also i tried to apply https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695448/6627564 this answer, but nothing changed.

Debugging shows that code executes up to `count = int(await app['db'].decr('counter'))` and then jumps somewhere to never return back.

Any help is greatly appreciated. As far as I understand, the event loop SHOULD return to execution after this line. Maybe the coroutine is somehow destroyed, but I haven't found any code in library doing this.

My problem is different from what is described in [Python Asyncio Websocket not detecting a disconnect on wifi but does on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075117/python-asyncio-websocket-not-detecting-a-disconnect-on-wifi-but-does-on-localhos)

First of all, my connections are all over localhost.

Secondly, the code after `async for msg in ws` loop actually starts executing, and debugging shows that `ws.close()` method is actually called. BUT there is a context switch on next `await` and execution doesn't go any further.

I have also tried using `ws = web.WebSocketResponse(heartbeat=1.0)` to activate ping-pong, but I can't see any messages in Dev Tools. I have added single `await ws.ping()` after `await ws.prepare(request)` and unfortunately no messages appeared in Dev Tools. Something is definitely going wrong here...

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested in this problem - the solution.

There are three issues in this code). Two of them are actually unrelated to asyncio.

First of all, `app['websockets']` is `list` and for some reason `remove(ws)` fails to find correct `WebSocketResponse` instance and removes another `WebSocketResponse` from list.
The solution is to use `set()` instead of `list` for storing active websockets. This is because `set.discard()` uses `__hash__` magic method, and `list.remove()` uses `__eq__` method.  Unfortunately, I cannot find the implementation detail for `__eq__` in `WebSocketResponse` , but `__hash__` is using builtin `id` function which guarantees correct work.

Secondly, look at this lines

```
ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
....
......
for ws in app['websockets']:
   await ws.send_json({'msg': {'count': count}})
```

Local variable `ws` is overwritten in the `for` loop.
The solution is to just use other variable name for iterating, like `other_ws`

The third one is described in `aiohttp`'s documentation [Web Handler Cancellation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#web-handler-cancellation).

It states that on every `await` call the handler can be terminated, if client has dropped connection. This is exactly the case - on the first `await` after dropped connection my handler died. The solutions is provided in the documentation as well, I decided to use `asyncio.shield`
.